# Show the stack with all activation record instances, including static and dynamic chains

Tags: stack, computer-science

Show the stack with all activation record instances, including static and dynamic chains, when execution reaches the indicated position in the skeleton program below. Assume Bigsub is a level 1 and the order of subprogram invocation is Bigsub calls A, A calls B, B calls A, A calls C, C calls D.

```
procedure Bigsub;
    procedure C; forward;
    procedure A;
       procedure B;
       end;  {B}
    end;  {A}
    procedure C;
       procedure D;
      *** Here is the point ***
       end;  {D}
    end;  {C}
 end;  {Bigsub}
```

I have some questions similar to this one. I don't understand what exactly is asked, what are dynamic and static chains. I have this image below which shows the stack and that's what I understand, but I don't what those arrows represent. Also, does the image lack activation record instaces or is it good as a solution?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A static chain is a chain of static links that connect certain activation
record instances in the stack.
dynamic chains is a collection of dynamic links in the stack at a given time. 
In your case whenever you say this "calls" that then add a dynamic  chain there.As for static chain,  you just have to see which function is static to which one.one. Ok for example C is nesting D so C and D has static chain as so forth.